# How to make a picture displays on screen, and few seconds later remove iteself?

Tags: android, timer, andengine

How to make a picture displays on screen, and few seconds later remove iteself?
Like a tutorial at the beginning of a game, I know the timer handler is what I should think about, but how to can it?

Answer (score 4):

The [TimerHandler](http://code.google.com/p/andengine/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/engine/handler/timer/TimerHandler.java?r=f5e3aa1b465e41b32f493240fec38448e079d9b1) is an easy choice.

```
final Sprite picture = ...
....
TimerHandler removeHandler = new TimerHandler(secondsToRemove, new ITimerCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pHandler) {
        picture.unregisterUpdateHandler(pHandler);
        picture.setVisible(false);
        //Or:
        scene.detachChild(picture);
        //You should use the second option, as making the picture invisible does not detach it from your game.
    }
});
picture.registerUpdateHandler(removeHandler);
```